# Hadoop RIPE-NCC hadoop-pcap SemanticException

Tags: hadoop, hive, pcap, beeline

I've used this library before with no problems, but now, after re-adding the JAR, I get this error.

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 1:14 Input format must implement InputFormat. Error encountered near token 'pcaps' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Since I've used it before, I doubt there's anything wrong with the library. Is there an additional step I forgot about when adding the JAR files? Thank you.

Comment: check for permission

Comment: I made permissions rwx for all users, and it's still the same.